# Remove the language prefix from file URL

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, uri

More specifically url's to files in the body text.

So in my body text I have manually added

```
<a href="/sites/default/files/some_file.pdf" />some file</a>
```

to link to a file.
I'm using the Pathologic module which changes every url to use the correct base path and language prefix. But it also adds a language prefix to files I've linked to in my body text. This obviously breaks the link to the file.

I realise there are some ongoing multilingual issues with the Pathologic module but to my knowledge these aren't fixed yet.

So now I'm looking for a workaround that allows me to remove the language prefix from the url for links that contain /default/files/.

- Is this possible in .htaccess with mod_rewrite? If you first check if the url contains /default/files/ and then do a redirect or rewrite the url?
- Is there some hook you can use that can alter the url?
- Is this possible with the Pathologic module? I noticed in the API there's a hook_pathologic_alter function but the path it provides as an argument seems to be the part after the language prefix. I don't know if you can alter the first part.

Thank you in advance, any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: When it comes to a link in HTML body content, Its preferable to use full url.

Comment: Using a full URL doesn't work. Did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: This [answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/103932/how-to-prevent-a-multilanguage-installation-from-adding-the-language-prefix-to-a) may be of help to others.